# "Recently used" directories and files in bash

Tags: ubuntu, directory

In Firefox under Ubuntu, when I try to save some webpages to my local computer by Ctrl+S, there will be a window popping out for me to select the destination, where I can choose "Recently Used" directories and files. I believe "Recently Used" is maintained by Ubuntu.

Some questions:

1. I found that only those directories or files that are recently created or changed will be shown under "Recently Used". For those recently visited without being modified, they seem not be counted as recently used, but sometimes I hope they can be counted.
2. Also there is a very limit length of history for what have been recently used, but sometimes I want to have a longer history.
3. Can I view a list of recently used directories and files in terminal? I am using bash.

Comment: The "Recently Used" list comes from the GTK+ library that Firefox uses on Linux.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about it to give a real answer, but this may help: http://confluence.za.net/blog/?p=293

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
ls -ltu
```

but you need a `ext2-4` partition mounted with `atime` option enabled.

`Ubuntu` by default have the `relatime` option enables by default.

From `man mount` :

> atime
>   Do not use noatime feature, then the inode access time is controlled by kernel defaults. See also the description for strictatime and relatime mount options.
>
> relatime
>                 Update inode access times relative to modify or change time.  Access time is only updated if the previous access time was  earlier  than  the
>                 current  modify  or  change time. (Similar to noatime, but doesn't break mutt or other applications that need to know if a file has been read since the last time it was modified.)
>
> Since Linux 2.6.30, the kernel defaults to the behavior provided by this option (unless noatime was  specified), and the  strictatime  option
>                 is required to obtain traditional semantics. In addition, since Linux 2.6.30, the file's last access time is always  updated  if  it  is more
>                 than 1 day old.

Example in `/etc/fstab` :

```
/dev/mapper/raid1-home /home ext4 defaults,atime 0 1
```

Note : enabling this option have a cost in term of performance (disk I/O).

[More on atime, ctime, mtime](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.fr/2008/03/ctime-atime-and-mtime.html)

Comment: afair `atime` is enabled by default, there is no need to specify it in fstab.

Comment: Added mention about that (test ok on 12.04)

Comment: Ubuntu have `relatime` by default, not `atime`, post edited accordingly

Comment: @rush That hasn't been the case for a few years. Linux defaults to `relatime` since kernel 2.6.30.